# How to obtain the matter Lagrangian from the stress-energy-momentum tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$?

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, lagrangian-formalism, potential, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I have obtained the components of stress energy momentum tensor
\begin{align}
 T_{tt}&=\frac{\Phi^2}{2\pi\mathcal{G}r^2 \left(1+2\Phi\right)^3}\\
 T_{rr}&=-\frac{\Phi^2}{2\pi\mathcal{G}r^2 \left(1+2\Phi\right)}\\
T_{\theta\theta}&=\frac{\Phi^2}{2\pi\mathcal{G} \left(1+2\Phi\right)^3}\\
 T_{\phi\phi}&=\frac{\Phi^2{\sin^2\theta}}{2\pi\mathcal{G} \left(1+2\Phi\right)^3}
\end{align} where $\Phi=\mathcal{GM}/r$, from the metric \begin{align}
ds^2={\left(1+2\mathcal{GM}/r\right)}^{-1}{dt}^2-\left(1+2\mathcal{GM}/r\right){dr}^2-r^2{d\Omega}^2. \end{align} Does this help to calculate the matter Lagrangian $(L_m)$ and hence, the Euler's-Lagrange equation?

Comment: It's difficult, but I think that based on these forms you can guess that the source is a scalar field. The energy momentum tensor blows at the schwarzchild horizon, it strongly reminds me of a minimally coupled scalar field.

Comment: Yes, we may treat  the source as scalar, but how to say "energy momentum tensor blows at the Schwarzschild horizon" as there is no definite horizon and the line element is not the Schwarzschild solution?

Comment: Oops I just saw the plus sign so there's no horizon. However based on these forms I can see that $\rho \neq -p_r$ which immediately discards the possibility that this is sourced by a Non-linear electrodynamics Lagrangian. Also the fact that $T_{tt}=T_{θθ}$ reminds me of the behavior of a scalar field.